# ./gradlew assembleRelease build failing when updated to react native 59.8 & gradle to 5.1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Before updating  react-native to 59.8 and gradle to 5.1, I can take build using ./gradlew  assembleRelease. When I updated react native to 59.8 and gradle to 5.1, I got following error

```
 * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-app-settings:verifyReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  \node_modules\react-native-app-settings\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  \node_modules\react-native-app-settings\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  \node_modules\react-native-app-settings\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2714: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  \node_modules\react-native-app-settings\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:2715: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

But If I use `./gradlew bundleRelease` the gradle successfully building the aab file. the problem only happening on `./gradlew  assembleRelease`.  How can I generate an apk file? below is my gradle settings

```
     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
}
```

//

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

//

```
 ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. I just replaced `./gradlew  assembleRelease` to `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`. You should try.

**EDIT**: There's another way. After some research, I found this code `subprojects { subproject -> afterEvaluate{ if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) { android { compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion } } } }` Put it before EXT In android/gladle. And you'll be able to keep `./gradlew assembleRelease`

The problem was conflict with buildtools from dependencies vs buildtools from android project